# phpMyAdmin configuration storage is not completely configured message

Tags: phpmyadmin

Today i have updated my PhpMyAdmin to 4.1.2
Now when i log in to PMA i am getting the message:

The phpMyAdmin configuration storage is not completely configured, some extended features have been deactivated. To find out why click here.

When i click on the link:

PMA Database ... not OK [ Documentation ]
General relation features Disabled

Do i need this features? Or i can ignore that message? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You do not need the features to use phpMyAdmin. You can read more about what they include in the [phpMyAdmin documentation](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#phpmyadmin-configuration-storage).

To disable, just remove the corresponding lines from your config.inc.php (you can start [here in the documentation](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_Servers_pmadb); each entry up to and including `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords']` relates to the phpMyAdmin Configuration Storage features; if you have any of those lines in your config.inc.php you can simply remove them). You also may have `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser']` and `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass']` entries, which *generally* are only used for the Configuration Storage features as well and in most cases can be removed.

Answer (score -1):

VestaCP Team made and successfully tested error fixer for phpMyAdmin (no more annoying message "The phpMyAdmin configuration storage is not completely configured, some extended features have been deactivated"). We hope that fix will be useful and will help users.

Page on Github: https://github.com/skurudo/phpmyadmin-fixer

What the script does:

- works from user root;
- changes inside /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php, fixes value;
- makes a backup of /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php in /root folder;
- adds in a mysql pma user / and the table phpmyadmin (if the user "pma" or the table "phpmyadmin" already exists, the script will delete those!);
- download and add table for database phpmyadmin;
- clean temp files, leftover pma.txt (contains password for pma@localhost) and old config;